# getting current active viewController in UITabBarControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to implement a scrollToTop method on all of my `viewControllers` in my `UITabBarController`. The following is a method in the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and triggers, when I select a tab.
The problem is, that I only want to scroll to the top of the `viewController`, when the `viewController` is active. So that the user can switch tabs without losing the scroll position, but when he touches the tab in the tabBar of the currently active tab, it should scroll to the top.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    if viewControllerThatIsCurrentlyActiveInTabBar == viewController {
        scrollToTop()
    }
}
```

**Basically, I need that condition of the if statement above.** 
I tried: `viewController.isViewLoaded`, `tabBarController.selectedViewController == viewController`, `viewController.isBeingPresented`. None of those conditions worked. It would either not trigger `scrollToTop()` or it would trigger always so that you lose the scroll position when you change tabs because it would immediately scroll to the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a code in should select instead of didselect. As it is unable to find the previous controller after selection. below is the example code for it.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if tabBarController.selectedViewController == viewController {
        print("Same viewcontroller")
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: well that works, thanks. You only have to return true.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use below extension for getting top viewcontroller of tabbarcontroller.

extension UIViewController {

```
var top: UIViewController? {
    if let controller = self as? UINavigationController {
        return controller.topViewController?.top
    }
    if let controller = self as? UISplitViewController {
        return controller.viewControllers.last?.top
    }
    if let controller = self as? UITabBarController {
        return controller.selectedViewController?.top
    }
    if let controller = presentedViewController {
        return controller.top
    }
    return self
}
```

}

You can use above extension below

```
 if let rootViewController = UIApplication.top() {
    //do with Active view controller
}
```